# Warning: Can’t call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Inside App.js we have defined a table whose columns are defined in config.js file. Now we need to access a method of App.js from config.js file which in turn will call the setState method of App.js and modify the state. But that is not happening and throwing the following exception and set state is not executed.

Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the App component.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useTable } from "react-table";
import { a } from "./config";
import makeData from "./makeData";
const Styles = styled.div`
  padding: 1rem;
  table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    tr {
      :last-child {
        td {
          border-bottom: 0;
        }
      }
    }
    th,
    td {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0.5rem;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      border-right: 1px solid black;
      :last-child {
        border-right: 0;
      }
    }
  }
`;
function Table({ columns, data }) {
  // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    data
  });
  // Render the UI for your table
  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row, i) => {
          prepareRow(row);
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>;
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.columns = a;
    this.data = makeData(20);
    this.state = {
      clicked: false
    };
  }
  openrequestUrlLink() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      console.log("prevState", prevState);
      return {
        clicked: !prevState.clicked
      };
    });
  }
  hello() {
    console.log("hello");
    return (
      <a
        href="#"
        onClick={() => {
          console.log("########", this);
          this.openrequestUrlLink();
        }}
      >
        {"FirstName"}
      </a>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Styles>
        <Table columns={this.columns} data={this.data} />
      </Styles>
    );
  }
}
export const App1 = new App();
export default App;
```

//Config.js

```
import { App1 } from "./App";
export const a = [
  {
    Header: "Name",
    columns: [
      {
        Header: "First Name",
        accessor: (data) => {
          return App1.hello();
        }
      },
      {
        Header: "Last Name",
        accessor: "lastName"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Header: "Info",
    columns: [
      {
        Header: "Age",
        accessor: "age"
      },
      {
        Header: "Visits",
        accessor: "visits"
      },
      {
        Header: "Status",
        accessor: "status"
      },
      {
        Header: "Profile Progress",
        accessor: "progress"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

[Link to code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-noether-31i9s?file=/src/config.js:0-629)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do i tweaked the code little bit i don't know [if this what you are trying to achieve.](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-wildflower-og3vu?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: this.setState does not exist anymore after you have clicked the link. Its trying to set the state, but it can't because the component has updated after clicking the link

Comment: yes because he is instantiating the class like this `export const App1 = new App();`.